# How to run terminal command from php file

Tags: php, web-interface

I have a python file on my raspberrypi that makes an led blink, which i made executable with `chmod +x file.py` so that in terminal i can run `./file.py` and the led blinks. I then wrote a php file (in the same directory as file.py)

code

```
<html>
<head>

    <title id = "my_title"> my page </title>

</head>
<body>

    <button id="my-button"> Button </button>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to run `file.py` when i push the button, maybe with `system ("./file.py");`. But when i putt this directly in the code

```
<?php
    system ("./file.py");
?>
```

it doesnt do anything except print on the site `Number of arguments: 1 arguments. Argument List: ['./file.py']` (`ls` works as expected). How might i go about running file.py when Button is pushed, and why won't `system` run `./file.py`. Thanks

Comment: Try using the complete path to the file. Is file.py executable? Can you edit your question and include the contents of file.py and an ls -la of the directory it is in.

Answer (score 1):

Does your `file.py` start with a correct shebang line? (i.e. `#!/usr/bin/python`)? That's how the system decides which interpreter to use when you're trying to execute the script.

In any case, you can just specify the interpreter in the `system` command itself:

```
<?php
    system ("python ./file.py");
?>
```